# SharePoint 2k13 http Error 503 service unavailable in SharePoint Web Services web app

Tags: iis, exchange-server, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I am trying to install and configure SiteMailBox on SharePoint and when i execute the `.\Set-SiteMailboxConfig.ps1` i get the error :

> Get-SPAppPrincipal : The HTTP service located at
>   `http://app:32843/87f2cfd3c96f4130b4f269d7cae8d99b/AppMng.svc` is unavailable.
>   This could be because the service is too busy or because no endpoint was found
>   listening at the specified address. Please ensure that the address is correct
>   and try accessing the service again later.

I went to IIS Manager and i wanted to verify my SharePoint Web services status, so i wanted to browse to the `http://localhost:32843/Topology/topology.svc` and i got the http 503 error service unavailable... According to this [thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101550/sharepoint-web-services-web-site-error-service-unavailable-http-error-503-the-s)

Can anyone suggest me how can i solve this probelm please ?or even some suggestions?
My appManagement is set up and here is my IIS site with its bindings : [image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

Changed your Admin Password??
Need to fix all login references

See Application Pool -> Advanced Settings 
    -> Identity